# Excluding files from rewrite .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(font-awesome|fonts|template_source|content-loader.php|builder-loader.php|page-actions.php)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|mp3|wav)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

To be honest, I have no idea what the last line does.
All I know is that I need to exclude files and that putting a file-name in the "RewriteRule ^"-part should exclude a file.

The problem is that I am using AJAX to call a php-file:

```
$(".sortable").load("page-actions.php/add_page",{siteID: 2});
```

I want to call the function "add_page" in the file "page-actions.php".
How can I create an exclude for this?

Comment: Whether you are using AJAX should not matter in this respect. In fact, the code you have already would seem to be applying the exclusion already - providing this is the correct .htaccess file. So, what is (not) happening exactly? (The "last line" routes all requests for static files through `index.php`.)

Comment: Well, the AJAX call isn't executed, because the url: /page-actions.php/add-page does not exist in the URI-table from my database. --- In short: the rewrite engine still redirects my call to the index.php.